# Can you become a mermaid in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have seen videos about people turning into mermaids and being able to breathe underwater yet I have tried it myself and have failed to complete it. Is it actually true?

Comment: Flagging as off-topic as it seems to be a mod request.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. This is in no way a mod request.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer *Not a request for a mod to be created, but a request to identify a mod.

Comment: I don't want a mod to be created. Look at these videos:

Comment: I don't think it's a good question, because a simple Google search provides the answer, but it's still on-topic for this site.

Comment: Look at this video: https://youtu.be/ni8P30YybTs

Comment: [**This is a mod**](https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/1710172-forge-mermaid-tail/). The only other way to **simulate** this would be to change your skin, and possibly either change your game mode, or use commands to apply water breathing constantly.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't a way to become a mermaid as such, and they do not exist in minecraft without mods. Now that you've linked a video, it looks like the [Forge Mermaid Tail Mod](https://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/1710172-forge-mermaid-tail/), but another example is the [Mermaid Mod](http://test.voidswrath.com/mods/1-7-10-mermaid-tales-mod-installer/).

However, one thing you can do **without** Mods to get similar effects is to consume a Water Breathing and Night Vision potion. This will allow you to see and stay underwater for longer periods of time - without the tail, of course.

A Water Breathing potion is created by brewing a water bottle with nether wart to create an Awkward potion and then brewing it again with a Pufferfish.

A Night Vision potion is created by brewing a water bottle with nether wart to create an Awkward potion and then brewing it again with a GoldenCarrot.

You can increase the duration of each by brewing it another time with some redstone dust.

Answer (score 3):

Err, no. Mermaids are not a thing that exist in minecraft. Perhaps you are confused about one of the many mods that provide features like that.